# C#: A hyphen in a preprocessor directive

Tags: c#, environment-variables, preprocessor-directive

I am reading the machine name from an environment variable `COMPUTERNAME` into a conditional compilation symbol:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;$(COMPUTERNAME)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After this, I declare a preprocessor directive to compile some code depending on the machine name:

```cs
#if MY-MACHINE
// Some code
#elif SOME-ELSE-MACHINE
// Other lines of code...
#else
// ...
#endif
```

However, the machine name can have a hyphen (`-`) in it, so I'm getting errors and I cannot build the project with this configuration. When typing the code above in Visual Studio, I get the error:

> Error CS1025  Single-line comment or end-of-line expected

and when building even without the conditional compilation statement, I get a warning:

> Warning   MSB3052 The parameter to the compiler is invalid, '/define:MY-MACHINE' will be ignored.

How to get around this? Is there some way to "escape" the conditional compilation symbols. Or should I just give up with this and read the environment variable runtime?

Comment: Using an arbitrary value is a conditional compilation symbol is just a bad idea. If you want conditional builds per machine, doing that in the build script is definitely the right idea (`<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ComputerName)'=='MY-MACHINE'"><DefineConstants>MYMACHINE</DefineConstants></PropertyGroup>`). But ideally, nothing should depend on the *machine* used to build things; define meaningful switches based on behavior of the code. If you need the build machine name embedded as a constant in the code (for whatever reason), you could use a T4 template.